# What's wrong with my largest prime finding function?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, primes

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my JS function. I'm trying to find the largest prime factor of a given number. 
It worked when called with 2 or 4, but fails with 3.

**Jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/prashanthcr/23y59nLa/
(It's towards the bottom of the JS part)

**JS:**

```
var problem3 = function(num) {
    var max = 0;
    var i = 3;
    var prime;
    while (num%2==0) {
        num/=2;
        max=2;
    }
    for (num;num>1;i+=2) {
        prime = true;
        for (var j=3;j<=Math.ceil(sqrt(i));j++) {
            if (i%j==0) {
                prime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (prime==false) {
            continue;
        }
        if (num%i!=0) {
            continue;
        }
        while (num%i==0) {
            num/=i;
            max=i;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('answer3').innerHTML = max;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `sqrt` is defined under `Math`. Use it like this:

```
for (var j=3;j<=Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(i));j++) {
```